# Where can I find wls-api.jar?

Tags: java, weblogic

Apparently I need wls-api.jar to compile the following:

```
import weblogic.security.principal.WLSUserImpl;
```

I've downloaded and extracted wls1213_dev.zip and added weblogic-classes.jar, but the WLSUserImpl class seems to be elsewhere.

Where can I find wls-api.jar (or the right jar file)?

Comment: 2500+ views and off-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/overview.htm#WLPRG134):

> The wls-api.jar file is located in the wlserver/server/lib directory
>   of your WebLogic Server distribution

Comment: Thank you. I installed weblogic server and located it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to ask you these basic questions first but, did you look at this?

[Which JAR contains the weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788311/which-jar-contains-the-weblogic-servlet-security-servletauthentication-class)

- Did you also check  the classpath to your server libs (and checked if
  provided)?
- If you are using Maven, do you have the following

  ```
          <dependency>
              <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
              <artifactId>wls-api</artifactId>
              <version>${weblogic.version}</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
  ```

Ref : [Using maven as build tool for Weblogic 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287335/using-maven-as-build-tool-for-weblogic-10-3)

I don't mean to offend you by underlining these simple checks first but that would be the first things I would have done.  Let me know. Thx

Comment: In which maven repo can I find the dependency you have listed?